# Turn any finite energy function into a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Suppose I have a continuous function that goes to zero at minus and plus infinity (not a finite support function). Can I turn that function periodic if I use the convolution with a sum of Dirac deltas?

Comment: Are there no other assumptions on the function?

Comment: It depends on how fast it goes to 0 at the infinities. If it goes like $\frac 1 {|x|}$, then convolving with a train of deltas (of same coefficients) will end up accumulating too much mass everywhere.

Comment: Why is that exactly? I thought that if the signal spectrum goes to zero at both ends and is continuous for all f, then we would have non infinite Fourier coefficients and they would tend to 0 as f->infinity, so in the time domain the series should converge. But maybe I am wrong.